# iOS7 unable to access HTML5 localStorage, if Cookies is disabled

Tags: ios, html, cookies, local-storage, ios7

On iOS7, while trying to access HTML5 localStorage object via JavaScript, stops execution of Javascript. It works correctly in previous iOS versions.
The app runs perfectly when the app is freshly installed and launched. But then, I close the app and launch again, it does not work and fails on accessing localStorage.

To disable cookies, I have used below code:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];
```

To access localStorage, I have used below code:

```
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<script>alert('hello world');alert(localStorage);</script>" baseURL:nil]
```

I have gone through the iOS7 docs but could not find any update related to this issue. Has anyone faced this too? Please share any information regarding this, would be very helpful. Any workarounds for this?

Thanks

Comment: would love to hear what you discover. we're facing the same issue.

Comment: I could not found a fix for this. I can not enable Cookies so finally I had to change my code both Server side and App side. I am saving data in UserDefaults, communicating with webpage via executing javascript on my WebView and using a native-Javascript bridge to callback my webpage. I am not sure how much it helps you. Since I had control over server-side code so it is working for me.

Comment: Another info is that I had filed a bug for this issue. Apple has closed my bug report by saying that it is a duplicate of another bug report. So, atleast, this implies that Apple has accepted this as a bug and hopefully they will fix it. But God knows when:)

Comment: Because of this localStorage issue(when cookies disabled), Youtube videos are not playing in UIWebView and every other site is not working properly if they are using localStorage and you have disabled Cookies in your app. God knows, when will Apple is going to fix this

Comment: thanks! how did you change code app side to enable cookies?

Comment: I have not enabled cookies. But if you want to enable cookies, write this in your code :     [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];

Comment: if you didn't enable cookies, how did you fix this on the app side?

Comment: I have stopped using HTML5 LocalStorage. I am saving data in a file and sending that to webpage via (UIWebView)native-Javascript bridge. With this approach your server side code must also be modified. But with the third-party webistes, we cannot do anything until Apple fix this.

Comment: ok, if we want to enable cookies only that one line is needed?

Comment: Yes, just put that line in your code.

Comment: @Crashalot Yes, we also faced a same problem. iOS 6 and below, the default cookie policy was to accept cookies ALWAYS and after iOS 7 they (Apple) changed it to accept NONE. So we have to use the above two lines where it is appropriate. In our app, we use Cookies everywhere, so we put it inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 1):

Granted this is an older post, but fwiw ...

Not sure if I have experienced this issue. Have used localStorage with and without cookies on several projects using iOS6/7.

The loadHTMLString provided looks a little peculiar to me ... so I tried this instead...

```
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('hello world');alert(localStorage);"];
```

... which worked fine, and showed the localStorage object as expected, with cookies disabled.

Tested in sim and on device, iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you can go through a blog here--
http://transitionalreality.blogspot.in/2014/03/html-5-local-storage-with-ios-app.html

I have implemented HTML5 local storage in my own way and this might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
window.localStorage
```

e.g:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<script>alert('hello world');alert(window.localStorage);</script>" baseURL:nil];
```