# Does anyone know how to save anything to the iPhone local storage?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, local-storage

**In my Mobile Web App I'm having trouble getting the offline-aspect to work (or anything, as the localStorage implementation is the backbone of my app.)**

I've been using Persist.js, and it's working, then not working. What is wrong with the implementation of Safari on iOS 7.0.4?

I don't know what to do at this point. It's telling me it has exceeded the quota, but it's just like 10kb of information that I want to store in the local storage in total.

I've been stuck at this for a little less than a week, and it's making me question the integrity of Apple.

My error is as follows, if my question for WHAT ELSE TO DO isn't clear enough:

`QuotaExceededError: DOM Exception 22: An attempt was made to add something to storage that exceeded the quota.`

**Cookies are too small, and I am not browsing in private.**

Comment: just use `localStrorage` global object. https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iphone/conceptual/safarijsdatabaseguide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html

Comment: What's the underlying implementation of Persist?

Here's how you can request for more storage per app:

    var db=openDatabase('mydb','1.0','mytable',1*1024*1024); //request 1 MB storage
    
    db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('create table if not exists mytable(...)'); //create your own table here
    });

This is supported in Webkit browsers such as Chrome, Safari and Mobile Safari.

Comment: iphone like to sandbag localStorage on UIWebView-based applications so that "real" apps perform better.

Comment: I have worked with local storage on iPhone and I believe I know what this question is asking. Please reopen the question?

Comment: Please check if Cookies are disabled in your Safari Preferences. If yes then enable Cookies or just reset your Safari. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932147/ios7-unable-to-access-html5-localstorage-if-cookies-is-disabled

Comment: @san My cookies were never disabled. It's a web-app.

Comment: If your code is working on iOS6 and not on iOS7, then I guess your Cookies are disabled somehow. AFAIK, I faced this same issue with Cookies disabled. Are you using PhoneGap or something similar?

Comment: Have not tested it on anything but iOS7. I'm not using PhoneGap, it's a non-jailbroken phone, should be configured with the most standard settings.

Comment: I am not sure if I can help any further with my knowledge. But, again I would suggest you to check thoroughly if Cookies are disabled or not. Test it on iOS6 device too.